# Windows Phone: Targets, Branding

Tags: windows-phone-7, target

i have an app that will be shipped by different providers. So i need to exchange the backgrounds etc, ss there is probably some kind of unique identifier for each app i also need different projects for that. What's the best practice to do this on windows phone ? Do i have to write own "Wrapper"-Projects ? (In iOS there is a concept called targets where i just link relevant branding files, appname, identifiers etc)

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XAML, you can use Styling and Templating to dynamically change the whole look and feel of your application.

The same principal applies to Windows Phone apps as well. Then all you got to do is, maintain different style xaml files and apply them to create unique builds, or once the application launches.

**Update:** As willmel suggests below, which I forgot to mention, localization techniques mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Video/gg241256) are a great way to maintain application strings.

**Update 2:** You can package your 'themes' into separate ZIP files, as demonstrated [here](http://www.jebishop.com/2009/11/25/dynamic-theming-in-silverlight-with-implicit-styles-plus-custom-build-events/) and use post build events and VS commands to create different packages. You can always call msbuild from the command line as well and customize your build process even further. You can use different manifests this way as well.

Comment: This is the best idea. Keep a very distinct set of string resources, image files, and styles. Use a build script to swap them based on the client project you're building for.

Comment: But the thing is that all of those apps will be in the Marketplace. So they need to be different applications/projects, right ?

Comment: Also, i need to exchange the splashscreen, app name... This comes from the WMAppManifest

Comment: @shorty Sounds like you're going to have to create some batch files to customize the build process further. See my update above.

Comment: @duluca i think that's the right direction, probably i have to replace the WMAppManifest somehow

Comment: @shorty I would appreciate if you could mark my post as an answer, if you've found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have provider information which is language specified, you can download a sample project here:
http://www.pocketpc.ch/windows-phone-7-entwicklung/158405-textbox-string-integer.html#post1381376

or another [here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229128), or in [VB](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=229345)

Once, you know the provider, you can select your resource file.
[That article](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/08/26/silverlight-string-localization.aspx) from Tim Heuer can show how you can work with less work for different situations like used in XCode iOS. Additional to strings you can use image URL as well.

[image: Resources]

Comment: it's not about language, but splashscreen appnames etc... Also there will be MULTIPLE applications just with branding differences in the marketplace

Comment: If you want that splash-screen depends on provider, I think splash screen is the only thing which needs a re-complilation using Visual Studio. I heard there should be a solution for splash screen. I have not found any and I don't care about because after splash, I can show needed informations using templates (provider/language). If you want to know how to handle on "Marketplace" (like AppStore) then you just can do it the very same way like on itunesconnect. Just upload an image / icon and description for each language.